# JSON encoding error?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have the following code built using the Requests module:

```
import json
import requests
import jsonobject
import simplejson

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics'
params = {
            'category': 'shots',
            'subcategory': 'zones',
            'statsAccumulationType': '0',
            'isCurrent': 'true',
            'playerId': '',
            'teamIds': '',
            'matchId': '',
            'stageId': '9155',
            'tournamentOptions': '2',
            'sortBy': 'Rating',
            'sortAscending': '',
            'age': '',
            'ageComparisonType': '',
            'appearances': '',
            'appearancesComparisonType': '0',
            'field': 'Overall',
            'nationality': '',
            'positionOptions': '%27FW%27,%27AML%27,%27AMC%27,%27AMR%27,%27ML%27,%27MC%27,%27MR%27,%27DMC%27,%27DL%27,%27DC%27,%27DR%27,%27GK%27,%27Sub%27',
            'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
            'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
            'isMinApp': '',
            'page': '1',
            'includeZeroValues': '',
            'numberOfPlayersToPick': '10'
            }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print responser.status_code
responser = json.loads(responser.text.replace("'", '"').decode('cp1252'))
print responser
```

This is causing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\counter.py", line 41, in <module>
    responser = json.loads(responser.text.replace("'", '"').decode('cp1252'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can see from the status code 200 that the HTTP request was successful, but I am still getting the above error. I have replaced single quotes with double ones as this is an issue I have experienced with this site before. I have also used to the decoding method compatible with Windows Command Shell, but am still having trouble.

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have text that you can decode; you still have bytes.

Comment: Why are you doing a search and replace on your response? What sort of response are you expecting? Try doing `json.loads(responser.text.decode(encoding='cp1252'))`

Comment: @rpgillespie utf-8 encoding doesnt work very well with command shell for none english language characters, whereas the encoding i have used does. either way your suggestion did not work. the expected response will be a set of nested lists. json only allows double quotes, where as the data returned could contain single, hence the substitution.

Comment: Why would your server return non-valid JSON?

Comment: Also, why not just do `responser.json()`?

Comment: @RPGillespie i have no idea to be honest with you, the data is basically what would be in an XHR request used to refresh a table. at a guess i would say because it contains text, which may not always be able to conform to json rules. responser.json() generates the error: 'Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 398
    elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal'

Comment: Well if the server returns valid JSON (which it should), then `responser.json()` works. Could you give us a textual form of the response you are getting?

Comment: responser.text does not produce any useable format. an XHR request is part of AJAX - asyncronousjson - asyncronousxml...there is no other way to get the data from an ajax request other than using json or xml...if the the contents of the ajax request is not standard json you have to make substitutions to the content, which you cant do with .json()

Comment: I know it's not a usable format, but posting it in string form will allow me to help you debug further. Right now I have no idea what this "JSON" response looks like.

Comment: I think the problem is really on the server's side since it returns those unusual first three characters. This might not be the solution you're looking for, but if you just want the working HTML, then you could print everything after those first three characters: `print responser[3:]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you think the response is JSON, but it's actually HTML:

```
ï»¿<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
<title>WhoScored.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script></head>
<body style="padding: 20px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; background-color:#222222;">
    <div style="margin:0 auto; padding: 40px 20px; width:560px; background-color:#fff;">
        The page you requested does not exist in <a href="http://www.whoscored.com">WhoScored.com</a>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript"> if (!NREUMQ.f) {NREUMQ.f=function() {NREUMQ.push(["load",new Date().getTime()]);var e=document.createElement("script"); e.type="text/javascript"; e.src=(("http:"===document.location.protocol)?"http:":"https:") + "//" + "js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-100.js"; document.body.appendChild(e);if(NREUMQ.a)NREUMQ.a();};NREUMQ.a=window.onload;window.onload=NREUMQ.f;};NREUMQ.push(["nrfj","beacon-2.newrelic.com","47235c2cb5","2727698","MVBVZhMHDEcCV0BdCwgaeV0TCwNYCk5RUDEUXBgcSw4WWQ8=",0,0,new Date().getTime(),"E2B84976C1F7ADB9","","","",""]);</script></body>
</html>
```

This is not valid JSON, and hence you can not use `json.loads` on it.

Also, AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript And XML, and is completely unrelated to the type of response you'll get back.

Comment: that response is a page not found one from the server. that is not a typical response i would expect, but it is still a server response. therefore i am getting a 200 code and not the data i was expecting. i need to have a look at the params being submitted as part of the URL again i think.